# No puedo levantar el server en Rails Mac os

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Al intentar levantar el server con Rails desde la terminal, resulta que tengo el siguiente problema:

```
MacBook-Pro-de-Brian:~ Brian$ rails new twitter
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems.rb:241:in `bin_path': can't find gem railties (>= 0.a) (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
    from /usr/local/bin/rails:22:in `<main>'
```

Comment: ¿Cómo instslaste rails?, ¿utilizaste rvm, rbenv, chruby o ninguno?

Comment: rvm Gerry gracias

Answer (score 0):

En mi caso se soluciono usando: `gem install bundler` y luego `gem install rails`